# NSDragOperationGeneric meaning

Tags: macos, cocoa, drag

I'm using Drag'n'Drop functionality in my application, and facing the following problem: user can force 'NSDragOperationGeneric' dragging operation, pressing the Command key.

And, what actually should I choose to do with this operation type? Are there any good practices with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything that makes sense for your app. In most cases, it's fine to treat it as a synonym for `NSDragOperationCopy`.

In fact, I'm a bit surprised by the question. Usually, `NSDragOperationGeneric` is the baseline for drag-and-drop. That is, when you decide to support drag-and-drop in your view, whatever that means for your view is what `NSDragOperationGeneric` represents. Then, the other drag operations can be specializations or modifications of that. You ask yourself "What does it mean for a drop to be a copy drop or a move drop instead of just a normal drop?" and go from there. (In some cases, there's no difference.)

Comment: Thanks. Probably I get the Cocoa's drag'n'drop idea wrong, thinking that dragging should fit into Move/Copy/Delete/Private operations.

Comment: I'm still confused. I'm in fact surprised you're surprised by the question! :) Maybe I've got the idea wrong too.

Comment: My doubt is, the documentation says "The operation can be defined by the destination". But according to your answer it looks like it is defined by the source. I'll be surprised if a copy mouse pointer is shown by the destination forcing a generic operation and copy is what the destination considers to be the default, but the source removes the dragged items because move is what the source considers to be the default!

Comment: Basically, how do the source and the destination in a cross-application drag and drop understand what each other mean by a generic drag and how and by whom is the appropriate mouse pointer appearance communicated to the OS? Because, it looks like by default the OS shows the normal mouse pointer which unfortunately is the same as the one shown for move operation!

Comment: What I can conclude by this deep probing is that the source and the destination do whatever makes sense to them and this is clearly indicated to the user by a normal mouse pointer. The fact that there is no special mouse pointer for move operations is probably a bug! The last part is what doesn't quite fit but this is the best explanation I'm able to come up with so far.

Comment: For a generic drag, the source doesn't understand what will happen. It's only supplying data. A move requires that the source do something special, so only `NSDragOperationMove` will cause that. The destination alone can't force a move if the source didn't offer that, so "generic" can never mean a move. The fact that the cursor is normal for a move does not mean that a normal cursor implies a move. A normal cursor means the normal operation given the source and destination, which is something the user is supposed to understand (as they do in the Finder).

Comment: But in Finder, the generic operation is to move! At least for `NSDraggingContextWithinApplication` (because of which they're able to handle it that way). This is evident when dragging a file/folder to a different device's folder (such as that of a pen drive) and forcing the generic operation by pressing the command key. How does this fit in?

Comment: Who says that the generic operation is to move? Drags within an application work differently than drags between applications. The Finder may very well include `NSDragOperationMove` in the allowed operations when dragging to itself and not when dragging elsewhere. If an application accepts a drag from the Finder using `NSDragOperationGeneric`, the Finder doesn't delete the dragged file, does it? If not, then the Finder didn't interpret the successful drag as a move operation.

Comment: Even if the Finder includes `NSDragOperationMove` in the allowed operations when dragging, if the user presses command when dragging, the `draggingSourceOperationMask` always returns only 4 or 0 depending on whether the source allows generic or not. So, for drag within application, generic usually means move and for drag outside application, generic usually means anything appropriate to the destination but with no reaction at the source. Right?

Comment: Like you said, Finder and Text Edit don't delete when we press command and drag to a test application which performs a generic drag operation. However, Finder and Text Edit perform a move when we press command and drag within the same window. Finder moves even when doing that across Finder windows whereas Text Edit copies (despite showing the generic mouse pointer) when doing that across Text Edit windows. So, it looks like generic simply means whatever is sensible given the source and the destination like you said. But it takes a lot more to understand fully! At least for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: As a user, it's kind of weird that though I press the command key saying I really want to move the text to the other Text Edit window, and the app responds by showing a generic pointer as against the default copy operation it would do which it indicates with the green + icon for the mouse pointer, it ends up not moving but just copying!